# php displaying image from stored path?

Tags: php, image

UPDATE.

I can only display the images inside a query e.g.

```
if($Result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
{
$img = $row['path'];
echo '<img src="'.$img.'">'; 
}
}
```

I want to display them inside a table but this code doesn't work :

```
<td class="tcgimagecell" colspan="5"><?php echo '<img src="'.$img.'">'; ?></td>
```

BELOW ISSUE RESOLVED  :

I have images stored in a folder (uploads) and the path is stored in a database table in a field named path. I am trying to display the stored images.

```
$Link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Database);
$Query = "SELECT * FROM $images";

if($Result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
{
$img = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';
}
}
```

Comment: You need to be using `$row` instead of `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

Your folder permissions for "uploads/" might not be set to public read.  Have you checked those already?  What is the URL that is output for your image?  Have you tried Copying URL and linked directly to it from your browser?  If the URL is coming back blank, try $row instead of $_FILES since you are just wanting the path to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Permissions are set to 777. If I type the full url in a browser the image is displayed.

Comment: @RazvanZ I cannot display the images inside HTML - I want to display them inside a table but this code doesn't work.

<td class="tcgimagecell" colspan="5"><?php echo '<img src="'.$img.'">'; ?></td>

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong: `$img = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];`.

Replace it with `$img = "uploads/" . $row[x];` where x is the number of column where file name is

OR

with `$img = "uploads/" . $row['columnname'];`. Here you have to replace `columnname`.

Comment: Thanks. Made the changes and noticed in firebird it was linking to the uploads directory twice i.e. uploads/uploads. Works with this :

$img = $row['path'];